# Trouble calling the toString Method

Tags: java

My method locateLargest() as show below is a method to find the coordinates of my largest value in my array. When I try to call the toString method with my locateLargest method in my main method I get an error that says: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method locateLargest(int[][]) from the type LocationTest.  Not sure how I can get around this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LocationTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numberInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: ");
    int row = numberInput.nextInt();
    int column = numberInput.nextInt();
    Location l1 = new Location(row, column);
    Location l2 = new Location();
    row = l1.getRow();
    column = l1.getColumn();
    int[][] array = new int[l1.getRow()][l1.getColumn()];
    System.out.println("Please enter the array elements: ");
    for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++){
            array[r][c] = numberInput.nextInt();
        }//end nested loop

    }//end for loop
    System.out.println(getMax(array));
    System.out.println(locateLargest(array).toString());

}



    public static int getMax(int[][] x){
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){

                if (x[i][j] > max)

                    max = x[i][j];
            }
    }
        return max;
    }


    public Location locateLargest(int[][] x){ 
        int maxValue = getMax(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
                if (x[i][j] == maxValue)
                    return new Location(i,j);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
class Location {
private int row;
private int column;

Location(){}//end constructor

Location(int row, int column){
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}//end arg constructor

public int getRow(){
    return this.row;
}

public int getColumn(){
    return this.column;
}

public String toString(){
    return "[" + row + "][" + column + "]";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public Location locateLargest(int[][] x){
```

to

```
public static Location locateLargest(int[][] x){
```

BTW, calling `toString()` is not necessary in this case. You can simply write:

```
System.out.println(locateLargest(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `locateLargest()` is non-static, so you can't call it from a `static` function such as `main()`. Change `locateLargest()` to `static`, since it doesn't appear to use any instance variables.

The reason you saw that compilation error is that `static` functions aren't allowed to call non-`static` ones.

Answer (score 0):

make `locateLargest(int[][] x)` as static method. The problem is non static method `locateLargest(int[][] x)` can't access from static method `main()`

```
public static Location locateLargest(int[][] x){ 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method should be static

```
public static Location locateLargest(int[][] x){ 
    int maxValue = getMax(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
            if (x[i][j] == maxValue)
                return new Location(i,j);
    }
    return null;
}
```

A `static` method (in your case `main`) cannot call a method or a any variable outside its method that is not also `static`.  Though, fyi, a non `static` method may call a `static` method of variable.

Also, like you did in your `getmax` method, you may want the inner loop like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++)

instead of

for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
```

Here

```
public static Location locateLargest(int[][] x){ 
    int maxValue = getMax(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++)
            if (x[i][j] == maxValue)
                return new Location(i,j);
    }
    return null;
}
```